# Time taken for species to become endemic

Tags: genetics, evolution, species, speciation, biodiversity

Is it known how long species take to become endemic? I know from examples such as Canada which have no endemics following the end of glaciation that the process must take at least 10 thousand years, but this merely demonstrates endemism must take a longer time. Has any technique been developed that provides some measure of the time needed for species to become endemic?

I am especially interested in the rate of endemism on a small and extremely isolated island such as St Helena.

Comment: From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endemism): `Endemism is the ecological state of a species being unique to a defined geographic location, such as an island, nation, country or other defined zone, or habitat type` There is no time component to it. If a species is found only in Canada, then it is endemic to Canada. If it is found only in your garden, then it is endemic to your garden.

Comment: @Remi.b That can probably be an answer and is the best OP is likely to get.

Comment: From wiki: "There are two subcategories of endemism: paleoendemism and neoendemism. Paleoendemism refers to *species that were formerly widespread but are now restricted to a smaller area*. Neoendemism refers to *species that have recently arisen*, such as through divergence and reproductive isolation or through hybridization and polyploidy in plants." So the time of the former is the one of the extinction of all populations of a species but one, while for the latter is the speciation time. Which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia > endemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endemism):

> Endemism is the ecological state of a species being unique to a defined geographic location, such as an island, nation, country or other defined zone, or habitat type.

There is therefore no time component to it. If a species is found only in Canada, then it is endemic to Canada. If it is found only in your garden, then it is endemic to your garden. No matter the duration in which the species has been found in this specific location.

That being said, in conservation biology, it is common to oppose endemic species with invasive species. An invasive species

[Wikipedia > invasive species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasive_species)

> An invasive species is a species that is not native to a specific location (an introduced species), and that has a tendency to spread to a degree believed to cause damage to the environment, human economy or human health

As the linked wikipedia page explains the concept of invasive species (or if you prefer the concept of non-endemism) is open to a lot of critics and is in no way well defined. There is no time limit under which we would stop considering an invasive species as invasive. It is rather the ecological impact of this species that will people to call it invasive or endemic based on purely subjective notions.

Comment: Endemism is dependant on time and location. A long time period is required and this is what my question addresses. The role of location in endemism is self-evident.

Comment: You seem to disagree with the Wikipedia definition, then. Can you please give a trusted source that would back up your claim?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confounding the concept of endemism with another one such as the concept of being [indigenous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_(ecology)) for example?

Comment: The Wikipedia statement that "endism is the ecological state of a species being unique to a defined geographic location, such as an island, nation, country or other defined zone, or habitat type" is a wordier version of my statement, which I believe to be self-evident, that Endemism is dependant on location. I also said it is dependant on time - this does not happen overnight. The question I am asking, which is not addressed by Wikipedia, is whether it is known how long a time endemism takes? I hope that makes my question easier to understand.

Comment: @user8654 I don't understand your comments but anyway. You might want to have a look at the edit in my answer. Your stance on the importance of time might come from invasive vs endemic discussions.

Comment: Could you add some non-wikipedia sources? I know this is your field, so I'm sure you have them. Wikipedia isn't reliable [by it's own standards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source). We have access to an expert (you). I'd love to see references that represent where you learned these things. For a really basic concept, that might be an authoritative textbook.

Comment: @DeNovo Is it my field though? :) I'm a population geneticists / computational geneticist but am not an ecologist and definitely not a conservation biologist. To be fair, I have published a paper on the evolution of invasiveness in domesticated sunflowers but I have not be brought to consider the semantic difficulties behind the concept of invasive vs native species. I don't know of a reference that talk about this semantic difficlties, sorry.